# Variable sending via the adsense tag to help report filtering

Tags: adsense

I'm currently trying to filter my adsense report to know how much money a referer makes me earn. To do so, is it possible to send a variable via the adsense tag and filter the reports with this var ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom channel for that.

1. Create custom channel: [link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65083?hl=en&ref_topic=1055501). Without assigning it to any ad unit.
2. Attach `data-ad-channel` attribute to slots that you want to track: [link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en), check "Setting custom channels dynamically" section.